# java how to config annotation scheduler fixedDelay in properties

Tags: java, spring, annotations, config

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 10 0 5 * ?")   
//@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000)
public void task() {
}
```

Is there a way to config :

in test env: Scheduled choose `fixedDelay = 10000`;

in product env: Scheduled choose `cron = "0 10 0 5 * ?"`

And What does this annotation grammar sugar `filed=value` called in java?

Comment: for specifying delay on properties, fixedDelayString must be used instead of fixedDelay as value from properties file are being read as string

Answer (score 8):

From spring `3.2.2` you can add this to config file and read it by Spring expression language  `(application.properties or application.yml)`

**application.yml**

```
 scheduler: 
    fixedDelay: 1000
```

In java class

```
  @Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${scheduler.fixedDelay}")
  public void task() {
  }
```

**Note :** Before `3.2.2` it will accept only long value but from `3.2.2` it will accept string also

Comment: Is there a way to choose between `fixedDelay = 10000` and `cron = "0 10 0 5 * ?"`? Because in test I want to use `fixedDelay` but in product I want to use `cron`

Comment: it is not possible and why you need to do in that way? @AylwynLake

Comment: ok. I thought my way to choose fixedDelay in test as cron in product was natual.